# Return default Enum value when Enum type is not known

Tags: c#, enums

I have a method that attempts to match string to DescriptionAttribute of enum values and then return the enum value. In case a match is not found, it should return a default value, which I thought I could just return 0. But it's not going to happen...

```
private Enum GetEnumFromDescription(Type enumType, string description)
{
      var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

      foreach (Enum e in enumValues)
      {
          if (string.Compare(description, GetDescription(e), true) == 0)
                    return e;
      }

      return 0; // not compiling
}
```

How should I code the above?

Comment: Why not pass the type parameter using generics?

Comment: Why have you tagged this with "iterator" and "yield-return"?

Comment: @Inerdial Can I? my enumType came from Type.GetReflectionOnlyType(somestringfromdatabase).

Comment: @JonSkeet my last post was cached and autofilled, and I overlooked the tags section. re-tagged

Comment: @Jake Ah, you probably can't in that case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
return (Enum) Activator.CreateInstance(enumType);
```

This will give you the default value for the type - which is what you want.

EDIT: I'd expected that you'd know the type at compile time, in which case generics are a good approach. Even though that appears not to be the case, I'll leave the rest of this answer in case it's of any use to someone else.

Alternatively, you could use [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) which already contains something like this functionality in a more efficient, type-safe form :)

```
MyEnum value;
if (Enums.TryParseDescription<MyEnum>(description, out value))
{
    // Parse successful
}
```

`value` will be set to the "0" value if the parse operation isn't successful.

Currently it's case-sensitive, but you could easily create a case-insensitive version. (Or let me know and I can do so.)

Comment: `Enum.ToObject(enumType, 0)` should be used.

Comment: @hazzik: *Should* be? Why *should*? What do you think the advantage of that is over the approach I've suggested? I'm not saying it won't work - just that there's more than one thing that will work, and if you're going to claim that someone *should* use one approach over another, you should justify that.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, and for me there is no much difference between these modal verbs, so sorry, if I offended someone. 

But for justification, I think it is better because `Activator.CreateInstance` is a generic solution for _all_ value types, but `Enum.ToObject` is specific for enums. And also it _probably_ works faster than activator. Also, `Enum.ToObject` is used inside `Enum.GetValues(t)`

Comment: @hazzik: I've just benchmarked it, and the results are inconsistent - but 10 million iterations takes "about a second" on my laptop either way, and I suspect a chunk of that is simply due to garbage collection. Your justification can work the opposite way too, note: `Enum.ToObject` is used to get *any* value of the enum, whereas `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)` is only used for parameterless constructors / the default value of value types, which is what's needed here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just tried 
`return (Enum) Activator.CreateInstance(enumType);`
with an enum without a 0 value, it still returns zero. 
You are John Skeet, so I'm gonna assume I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Scott: 0 is still the default value for *any* enum type, whether or not it has a declared 0 value. I'm not sure what you expected.

Comment: @JonSkeet I expected (naively) a valid enum value.  If 0 is going to be the default for any and all enum types, why go to all the trouble of the activator, just cast 0 to your enum type... then watch it fail when you try to use that value in any method that is expecting a valid enum value. (and thanks for such a prompt reply to such an old question, it really is appreciated)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the correct approach is

```
(Enum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, 0)
```

Because

- `Activator.CreateInstance` is generic solution for all value types and `Enum.ToObject` is a specific solution for enums, so `Enum.ToObject` declares clear intentions of the code.
- <s>`Enum.ToObject` *probably* works faster than `Activator.CreateInstance`</s>
- `Enum.ToObject` is used inside `Enum.GetValues` to retrieve values.

Answer (score 1):

default(T) will work for this. Get the type and use default. By default first element will be taken as Default value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work

```
return (Enum)enumValues[0];
```

Comment: No, that won't work if the enum doesn't define a value corresponding to 0. It will also throw an exception if the enum doesn't define *any* values.

Comment: @JonSkeet hmm... how do you even know the minute details off the top of your head? It's certainly not something that happens regularly?

Comment: @Jon I fail to comprehend why it wouldn't work. It just retrieves the first element form the array.

Comment: @user676571: Yes, but that's not the equivalent of returning the "0" element for that enum, which is what the OP appears to want. And in the case of an empty enum, that array would be empty, hence the exception.

Comment: @Jake: There are no particular details to remember here - it's just logical that if you've got an `enum Foo {}` then the array won't have any values, and if you've got `enum Foo { Bar = 5 }` then the only element in the array will correspond to value 5, not 0.

Comment: @Jon I was under the impression that OP wanted first element of the enum (which usually corresponds to 0, but it doesn't have to). Of course, if enum was empty, the code would throw, but I kinda thought it was understood.

Comment: @user676571: While it's *possible* that's what the OP means, he wrote: "it should return a default value" - and the default value for any enum type is the "zero" value for that type. It's *possible* that the first value of the enum would be okay, but it doesn't correspond to what the non-compiling code seems to try to do.